# Conver PL/SQL query to T-SQL that copyies values of row to another row via a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following PL-SQL query:

```
UPDATE TABLE
(
  Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
)
= 
(
  SELECT 
    Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
   FROM TABLE
  WHERE ID_COLUMN = 'ID OFF ROW TO COPY FROM'
)
WHERE ID_COLUMN = 'ID OFF ROW TO COPY TO'
;
```

It was written a long time ago in PL/SQL and its purpose seams to be to copy the values of a row to another row in the same table.
The application now also uses SQL Server and the query does not work there.
I have tried the following query:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET
Column1 = T2.Column1,
Column2 = T2.Column2,
Column3 = T2.Column3,
Column4 = T2.Column4
FROM TABLE T2
WHERE ID_COLUMN= 'ID OFF ROW TO COPY TO'
AND T2.ID_COLUMN = 'ID OFF ROW TO COPY FROM'
```

That does not give errors but it does not update correctly either.
I checked by doing a simple update on the row to copy from and then running the lower query.

Does not feel very nice to copy a rows values like this, doesn't work either. But not sure if it can be done with a query that is compatible with both t-SQL and PL/SQL

Comment: *"but it does not update correctly either"* Why doesn't it? Explain why what you have doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Side note, having queries that work in 2+ (R)DBMS products is pretty much a pipe dream. Though there are ISO/ANSI guidelines what a SQL dialect implements can be wildly different to another, and they are under no requirement to implement any/all the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a code, which is executable both on Oracle and SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET
Column1 = (SELECT T1.Column1 FROM Table1 T1 WHERE T1.Id = Table2.Id)
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Unfortunately, the UPDATE statement differs in features in these dialects of SQL, especially if you need to update one table based on another.